# Datalab Connection Issue || SSL Handshake Error

Tags: ssl, connectivity, google-cloud-datalab

When I use the 'datalab-connect' command in the CMD, I get the following error:
"Datalab Build failed with unexpected

> error:
>       ("bad handshake : Error([('SSL Routin es','ssl3_get_server_certificate','certificate verify failed')],)",)

When I previously got this error, I reach to our internal IT and I was told to copy paste a cacerts.pem file and make SSL_CERT_File environment variable to point to the location of the file.

This solved the issue. But I am getting the same issue again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried download and update cacerts.pem again?